# Trigger in SQL Server: derived column on INSERT

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I'm just getting my feet wet with triggers in SQL Server and I'm struggling with this challenge:

Create a trigger to do: whenever a software package is installed on a PC, the person who installs the software only needs to provide data for pack, tagnum, and instdate. The softcost column needs to be updated based on the packcost of the package.

```
CREATE TRIGGER software_on_install_fill_in
ON software
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    --declare the names and types of variables you will use
    DECLARE @software_pack char(4), @software_tagnum char(5), 
            @software_datetime datetime, @software_softcost numeric(10,2)
BEGIN
    --set the variables to values
    SET @software_pack = (SELECT software.PACK FROM software, inserted i)
    SET @software_tagnum = (SELECT software.TAGNUM FROM software, inserted i)
    SET @software_datetime = (SELECT software.INSTDATE FROM software, inserted i)

    UPDATE software
    --apply logic to auto update softcost column of inserted row
    SET @software_softcost = (SELECT package.PACKCOST 
                              FROM package, inserted i
                              WHERE SOFTCOST = @software_softcost)
END
GO

-- Try a test case, which fails
insert software(PACK, TAGNUM, INSTDATE)
values('ac11', '32494', '9/14/1998 0:00:01')
GO

--Try to see if contents of the table have changed, also fails
select * from software
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I think something's wrong with my insert statement because the trigger itself seems to execute properly. Am I doing this right??

Thanks

Comment: you cannot assumed there is only one record in the `inserted` or `deleted` table. These 2 tables contains records that are affected by the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement. You will need to re-write the trigger to handle that

Comment: `inserted` may have multiple rows so you cannot assign it to a variable.

Comment: "I think something's wrong with my insert statement..." Insert statement is OK. The trigger looks awful. You receive your error in each and every line after `--set the variables to values`

Answer (score 1):

Basically your trigger is not doing anything actually. It declare some variables, assign values to those variable and thats it.

Your trigger are assuming `inserted` table only contains one row. Which is wrong. The `inserted` table will contains all rows affected by your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement

You need to assume that the `inserted` contains several rows and treating it like a normal table. Only that it exists only within the `trigger` context.

As i don't have your related schema details, i assumed the PK is the `PACK` and attempt to re-write the trigger.

Anyway, the trigger should looks something like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER software_on_install_fill_in
ON software
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE  s
    SET SOFTCOST    = p.PACKCOST
    FROM    inserted i
        INNER JOIN software s   ON  i.PACK  = s.PACK
        INNER JOIN package p    ON  i.PACK  = p.PACK

END
```